# Data partitioning in SAP HANA

Tags: partitioning, hana

I have scenario here , i have 3 tables and i am anticipating they are going to grow in large size possibly over  2 billion records in future.

The application using these tables is yet to be deployed , i am looking here strategy for partitioning the table.

Do i create partition for these tables after the application is  deployed for production and seeing the growth rate of table data ( monitoring some threshold limit of no of records which i am not aware of now) or do i design partitions for  tables in schema before i deploy this into production?

If i have to partition can i partition on Range partitioning on timestamp column, ? on month or on year vale of timestamp?

Answer (score 0):

If you can already anticipate the growth with a good degree of certainty, then you should already start with a partitioning approach.
SAP HANA supports partitioning on elements of a timestamp (eg YEAR or MONTH). However, pay attention to whether this will actually give you a good data partitioning, as not all data gets generated in a constant volume over time (e.g. sensor data may be constant while retail sales data likely increases over time and seasonally)